# Why can't I access the exploded array element immediately?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Why can't I immediately access elements in the array returned by `explode()`?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
$username = explode('.',$thread_user)[1]; 
//Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[
```

But this code does:

```
$username = explode('.',$thread_user); 
$username = $username[1];
```

I don't usually program in PHP, so this is rather confusing to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, PHP simply does not support this syntax. In languages like Javascript (for instance), the parser can handle more complex nesting/chaining operations, but PHP is not one of those languages.

Comment: ^ the real answer. Even if you write a function that returns an invariant array, you still can't index the function call (as James' answer might lead you to believe), because it's simply a matter of the syntax not working.

Comment: +1 for Chuck's comment - clearly some defensive programming has allowed me to avoid learning PHP as fully as I should. (and maybe I shouldn't try to answer questions on the last day of a three-day weekend...)

Answer (score 6):

The reason it isn't obvious how to do what you want is that `explode` could return `false`. You should check the return value before indexing into it.

Comment: Thank you. I am not used to return values behaving like that and I missed that when I checked the PHP manual.

Comment: It's always seemed a little quirky to me, but it is useful, and no uglier than e.g. having to check calls to malloc in C for NULL returns.

Comment: It's actually just that the PHP syntax doesn't support this. You're simply saying it's intended that way to make people check their return values?

Comment: No, not exactly. Rather, I think this is one of the most useful ramifications of the decision not to support this syntax.

Comment: James, you're absolutely right that for PHP to support this syntax would add another layer of complexity owing to the fact that in PHP, a soft-typed language, you cannot guarantee the return type of a function. However there are other cases where PHP's parser does in fact allow such conditions may occur. In these cases, PHP simply attempts the closest typecast it can manage and throws a warning message. Try accessing `$userID[1]` where $userID is an integer, for example.

Answer (score 5):

It's version dependent. **PHP 5.4** does support accessing the returned array.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-115

Answer (score 2):

Since explode() returns an array, you may use other functions such as `$username = current(explode('.',$thread_user));`

Answer (score 1):

I just use my own function:

```
function explodeAndReturnIndex($delimiter, $string, $index){
    $tempArray = explode($delimiter, $string);
    return $tempArray[$index];
}
```

the code for your example would then be:

```
$username = explodeAndReturnIndex('.', $thread_user, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get it down to one line:

`$username = current(array_slice(explode('.',$thread_user), indx,1));`

Where `indx` is the index you want from the exploded array. I'm new to php but I like saying exploded array :)